# Content Length http request

Tags: html, http

What is the type of http request content-length, is it on bytes or kilobytes ?

here's my content-length :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in bytes. So that would be 5.02 kB in your case.

Answer (score 2):

As by [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2), this is a 'decimal number of octets' (bytes).

Answer (score 1):

The length of the request body in octets (8-bit bytes)